# Electric Potential for point charge

Tags: work, potential, potential-energy

I am in dilemma about my derivation for finding Electric Potential for a point charge and I know it is asked before but I didn't get the answer. So I am posting here.I asked this question conceptually previously but the answer didn't satisfied me. Any described detailed answer would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: I presume the previous question you are referring to is [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262125). If you were not satisfied with that answer, you should post a comment to say so - as you did [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266030) to dmckee, instead of posting a revised version of the same question. Note that editing your question will bring it to the attention of the community again, but posting a comment only reaches the person addressed. Your example to me in a comment (which example seems to be the same as the one above) should have been in your question.

Comment: The question u are referring @sammygerbil is not that one. I deleted that question. The question u presumed has some concepts of it in this one but this is not that question and I think this is not actually the another version of that question.  And if u know the answer of this please reply. It would be very helpful for me. And Thanx for the advice

Comment: All 3 of your questions (the 2 linked plus this one) seem to be variations of the same question about the sign convention for work and potential energy. The present question seems to be asking only "What is wrong with my calculation?" Such a question is *off topic* anyway, according to the site policy. If it is not a duplicate of the suggested question, it may be a duplicate of [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259612).

Comment: I didn't get how this question is duplicate of the marked question  "Work done relation to Potential Energy". I have posted in my question that "i didn't get the answers any detailed answer would be appreciated". I am not saying that other users who have markdown this question as duplicate are wrong. The thing is i am not able to understand those answers. If anyone knows a better explanation for this post please post the answer. It would be very very very much  helpful for me. Aplogizing for any inconvienience

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the integrand of the "standard formula" contains a dot product.   In your equation (3) you've expanded the dot product thus removing it.   You should not write vector arrows in equation (3).  The integrand in equation (3) contains *vector components*.

Comment: The equation (3) if u look clearly is derived from the previous equation. If "I don't put any vector arrows" in my equation (3) the electric potential V=-(kq/r).Also the dot product of equation (3) will give the previous equation (before 3rd equation) which will give me the "correct answer" V=kq/r